# How to send stored painless script id to spring data elasticsearch update query?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Updatequery.builder only has withscript(string script) function to send the script source , how to send the script id in case of stored script? . I am using spring data elasticsearch 4.1. Thanks

Edit to show the error with Spring data elasticsearch 4.2.1

Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("message","this is a test message to test");

UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(Query.findAll()).withScriptType(ScriptType.STORED) .withScriptName("updateScript01").withParams(params).build();
this.elasticsearchRestTemplate(updateQuery,IndexCoordniates.of("sampleIndex1"));

exception:
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: id is missing;2: script or doc is missing; at org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:26) at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest.validate(UpdateRequest.java:206)

Stored script in elasticsearch from kibana:
POST _scripts/updateScript01
{
"script": {
"lang": "painless",
"source": "ctx._source.message = params.message;"
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Support for using stored scripts was added in version 4.2. For usage see Sahil's answer.

**Edit:**

After looking at your sample code:

You need to use `updateByQuery()`,  not `update()`:

```
this.elasticsearchOperations.updateByQuery(updateQuery,IndexCoordinates.of("sampleindex1"));
```

btw: "indexSample1" as you had it is no valid Elasticsearch index name. Capital letters are not allowed in an index name.

Comment: Instead of script, i am providing script type and script name, but receiving the below error.                                                                                                                                                                              either script, document or query must be set
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.UpdateQuery$Builder.build(UpdateQuery.java:438)

Comment: This is the query used which is resulting in error: UpdateQuery.builder("sampleID")
     .withScriptType(ScriptType.STORED).withScriptName("updatescript01")
     .withParams(params).build();

Comment: do you have a query defined? If not, and you want to run the update on all documents use `Query.findAll()` as query parameter

Comment: I have tried that as well, it is still giving error for id and script fields.   Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: id is missing;2: script or doc is missing;
 at org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:26)
at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest.validate(UpdateRequest.java:206) Query used :  UpdateQuery.builder(Query.findAll()).withScriptType(ScriptType.STORED)
        .withScriptName("updateScript01").withParams(params).build();

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible, compilable and runnable example [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated the question to show the code blocks creating the error. Can you please check once?

Comment: please provide a minimal project that shows this behaviour, that can be checked out from GitHub or GitLab and that can be built with a `mvn package` or `gradle build`.

Comment: Please check the sample code creating the issue https://github.com/ramschavaa/spring-data-es.git

Comment: To update a document where you have the id, take the `update(Query)` method and add the id to the query object. I think it might have been better that in this case the parameter object would not be named _Query_, but it has this name since it was introduced long before I came into this project

Answer (score 0):

Use the below methods with ScriptType->Stored and name being id.

[image]